# How to select data from xml by T-SQL?

Tags: xml, t-sql

I have the table: TestXml with 2 columns(pk , xCol).
This is my table:

```
    create table TestXml (
pk int primary key, xCol xml)
on [Primary]
insert into Store.dbo.TestXml(pk,xCol) values (1,'<docs><doc id="12"><section> Section 1</section></doc>
<doc id="123"><section> Section 1</section>
<section> Section 2</section>
</doc>
</docs>'
)
```

the xml value , that I was insert looks like this:

```
   <docs>
  <doc id="12">
    <section> Section 1</section>
  </doc>
  <doc id="123">
    <section> Section 1</section>
    <section> Section 2</section>
  </doc>
</docs>
```

How can I take "`<section>`" element where "`<doc id = "123">`" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT c.d.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar (100)') AS Section
FROM Store.dbo.TestXml tx
    CROSS APPLY tx.xCol.nodes('./docs/doc') AS a(b)
    CROSS APPLY a.b.nodes('./section') AS c(d)
WHERE a.b.value('(@id)[1]', 'int') = 123
```

Comment: Thank you @mwigdahl for your example. This reasoning clears out my issue on how to dinamically read xml data types on SQL Server.