# How to read data from an XML variable?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql, xquery-sql

I've an xml variable with the below given format, and I do need to dinamically read and load into some T-SQL structure the element names and its respective fields values:

```
declare @InputXml   xml
Set @InputXml = '<Root RootName="rooNameValueHere">
            <Element Name="elementName">
                <SubElement Field="subelementFielName"/>
            </Element>
            <Element Name="otherElementName">
                <SubElement Field="subelementFielName1"/>
                <SubElement Field="subelementFielName2"/>
                <SubElement Field="subelementFielName3"/>
            </Element>
        </Root>'
```

Tips:
1 - The Root can contain N Elements
2 - Each Element can contain N SubElements
3 - I need to create a routine able to retrieve both all the information and also able to filter out by providing one Element Name (e.i.: for a given element, return all its subElements).

Right now, I've written this T-SQL to get subElements given one element name but I'm getting a null value:

```
select 
    t.c.value('@Field', 'nvarchar(10)') AS SomeAlias
from
    @InputXml.nodes('N/Root/Element[@Name = ''elementName'']//SubElement') t(c);
```

**Resolution**:

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671998/how-to-select-data-from-xml-by-t-sql) help me to clear out my issue. Thanks to all who responded.

Answer (score 2):

I removed 'N' char from beginning of query and it works :)

```
@InputXml.nodes('/Root/Element2[@Name = ''otherElementName'']//SubElement') t(c);
```

Comment: Would also work if the N were in the right spot, e.g. `@InputXml.nodes(N'/Root/...'`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select 
    t.c.value('@Field', 'nvarchar(100)') AS SomeAlias
from
    @InputXml.nodes(N'/Root/Element[@Name = "elementName"]/SubElement') t(c);
```

Result:

```
subelementFielName
```

Comment: I think the N should still be at the beginning (just in the right spot) to cover the outside chance that true Unicode data is ever contained in, say, an element name.